# I am trying to import large data from excel to SQL server, but it is giving as "AUTOMATION ERROR"

Tags: vba, excel

will this code works for large data ?
This code works fine for small data, but for large data it gives automation error, only few lines are getting loaded into database

```
Sub insertion()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim rsstring As String
Dim m, nrows As Integer
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\MPN-Materials.xlsx")
wb1.Sheets("sheet1").Activate
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PRATEEP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=MDM;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open sConnString
    Dim loRH As Excel.ListObject
    Set loRH = wb1.Sheets("MPN Materials").ListObjects(1)
    loRH.Parent.Activate
    loRH.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Select
    nrows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection)
 For m = 0 To nrows - 1
 rsstring = "insert into MPN_Materials (MPN_Material, Material_Desc, 
 Int_Material_No, MPN, Manufacture_ID,  Material_Grp, Material_Type, 
   Last_Change, UoM) values" _
        & "('" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 1) & "', " _
        & "'" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 2) & "', " _
        & "'" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 3) & "', " _
        & "'" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 4) & "', " _
        & "'" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 5) & "', " _
        & "'" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 6) & "', " _
        & "'" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 7) & "', " _
        & "'" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 8) & "', " _
        & "'" & loRH.DataBodyRange.Cells(m + 1, 9) & "'); "
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs = conn.Execute(rsstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `.TransferSpreadsheet` to get data from excel into access. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx) you can find the documentation.

Alternatively you can use the import function of access, generate an import specification that way and use it again later.